# Get logo url & alt in topmenu

Tags: template, logout

so I'm trying to add the logo to the topmenu.phtml but `<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>`, and `<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>` don't work (they return null/nothing)

Is there a way to call them from this template rather than the header.phtml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your template

> $logoSrc = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src');
>
> $logoAlt =  Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt');
>
> $imageurl = $this->getSkinUrl($logoSrc);